# Sum multiple value in one single looping

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what I want:

```
cr.execute(#some query)    
lines = self.cr.dictfetchall()
total_qty = 0.00
total_weight = 0.00
total_weight_net = 0.00
total_volume = 0.00
for line in lines:
    total_qty += line['product_qty']
    total_weight += line['weight']
    total_volume += line['volume']
```

is there any better way to do this kind of sum ?thanks

Comment: Why not have the *database* do the summing?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I still want to use the lines for another task, so I don't have to loop twice

Comment: I'd still use separate queries in that case. And if you are looping over the rows already, why not do both tasks in the one loop then?

Comment: @Edxz You asked for better way to do that and Martijn Pieters gave you good answer - use separate sql query. If you do it by your code, it will probably be slower and more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to find alternative looping method:

```
lines = [{"a": 10, "b":22},
        {"a": 11, "b":22},
        {"a": 12, "b":20},
        {"a": 15, "b":15},
        {"a": 15, "b":12}]

sumA = sum(itm["a"] for itm in lines)
sumB = sum(itm["b"] for itm in lines)
print sumA
print sumB
```

prints

```
63
91
```

Anyway, as @MartijnPieters suggested, getting the sums by sql query is very likely to be faster.